# Downloaded pdf file using appscript results in different pdf as if downloaded manually

Tags: google-apps-script

Downloaded pdf file using appscript results in different pdf as if downloaded manually
Can someone give an advice?  I have written appscript to download a report into pdf file.  I used to download manually, and all this time it shows as I expected. Recently, I tried to use appscript to download automatically, but the result is different from downloaded-manually.   Thanks for help me.

```
function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    ui.createMenu("JP Ranap")
    .addItem("Keperawatan-PDF","keperawatan")
    .addToUi();
}


function displaytoast(berita,judul,lama){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(berita,judul,lama);
}


function getFileAsBlob(exportUrl) {
 let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
     muteHttpExceptions: true,
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
     },
   });
 return response.getBlob();
}



function keperawatan(){
  var  bulanrekap = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('REKAP').getRange('S2:W2').getValue(); 
  var  tahunrekap = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('REKAP').getRange('S3:U3').getValue();   
  let blobpdf = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i0lJ8dyeAUXvdEsPIPvMgO5cUfYF5e0LG6h7RLzpwpM/export?format=pdf&gid=616353764&potrait=false");
  
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "xxxx@gmail.com",
      subject:"JP RANAP "+bulanrekap+" "+ tahunrekap+" [Unit DAMIANUS-GORETTY]",
      body: "Yth SDM, \n\nberikut kami lampirkan laporan JP RANAP Unit DAMIANUS-GORETTY bulan "+bulanrekap+" "+ tahunrekap+". \n\nAtas perhatiannya kami ucapkan banyak terima kasih. \n\nHormat kami, \n\ndr. Ramzi, SpAn. \n\n", attachments: [blobpdf.setName("JP RANAP "+bulanrekap+" "+ tahunrekap+" Unit DAMIANUS-GORETTY.pdf")]
      })
    
  displaytoast("JP RANAP sudah dikirim.","BERHASIL",15); 
  }
```

[PDF from downloaded using appscript, result in only 1 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRDBO.png)
[PDF from downloaded using manual from the menu, result in 2 pages, this is the first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxnRg.png)
[PDF from downloaded using manual from the menu, result in 2 pages, this is the second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXRW.png)

I don't know what to do.